# ruby if string includes strict characters

Tags: ruby

I have an array:

`array = ["abhor", "rage", "mad"]`

and I want to check if a string includes any word in that array - But only that word (not a substring).

```
string = 'I made a cake.'
count = 0
array.each do |word|
  if string.include? word
    count += 1
  end
end
```

However, the above does increment `count` by 1 because it's picking up the `word` `mad` from `made` in my string. How can I search for only mad and ensure `made` doesn't get counted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to go down the regex road, \b represent a word boundary.  This example, which includes all of the words in your sentence and a few which are fragments, correctly returns 4.

```
array = ["abhor", "rage", "mad", "I", "made", "a", "cake", "cak"]

string = 'I made a cake.'
count = 0
array.each do |word|
    if string =~ /\b#{word}\b/
          count += 1
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The [array intersection operator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-26) `&` is useful here.

Here's two options, depending on how you define "word":

1) If a word is any sequence of non-whitespace characters, then you can do:

```
array & string.split
```

In your example, this results in the intersection of array and words in string, which is empty.

2) If a word is any sequence of alphanumeric characters including _, then you can do:

```
array & string.scan(/\w+/)
```

For example if `array = ["abhor", "rage", "mad", "cake"]` then #1 above will be empty (because you have `cake.` with a period in the string) but will return `['cake']` for method #2.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```
array = ["abhor", "rage", "mad"]
string = 'I made a cake.'
string.split.count{|word| array.include?(word)}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with doing a simple split is that it won't take into account punctuation. What you need is a regex, which is a little more complicated.

```
array.each do |word|
  count += 1 if string.match(/\W#{word}\W/)
end
```

Comment: You might need to add an additional word boundary marker at the beginning of this regex to make sure that you don't catch certain substrings.  For example "enrage" =~ /rage\W/ is true but not /\Wrage\W/.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting up the words first.

```
words = string.split
count = 0

words.each do |word|
  count += 1 if array.include? word
end
```